# Using scalatest Suites

Tags: scalatest

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to use Suites to create a master test suite for my tests.

The test classes comprising the master suite look like this:

```
@DoNotDiscover
class Api_1_0_Tests extends FunSpec {
    describe("=================\n| API 1.0 Tests |\n=================") {
        it("Must test 1") { (pending) }
    }
}
```

The MasterTestSuite looks like this:

```
class MasterTestSuite extends Suites(new Api_1_0_Tests(), new Api_2_0_Tests(), new CacheTests()) with BeforeAndAfterAll {
    override def beforeAll(configMap: org.scalatest.ConfigMap) {
        println("Before!")
    }
    override def afterAll(configMap: org.scalatest.ConfigMap) {
        println("After!")
    }
}
```

This compiles but when run the Before! string prints but nothing else happens -- it hangs.

Comment: Hi,

I've recreated you example using scala-2.10 and scalatest-2.0.RC1 then I run test from SBT and it works. Which version of scalatest are you using?

Comment: scalatest exposes a function called info that will allow you to print along with the rest of the test output. Maybe that’s your problem?